# C#: While loops with the condition at the end

Tags: c#

In VB I can write a loop that always executes at least once. For example:

```
Do
   [code]
Loop While [condition]
```

Is there a way to do that in C#?

Comment: Someones going for the Peer pressure badge ;)

Comment: No, just switching from VB to C#. I took the time to learn the advanced stuff because its interesting, but I don't use C# enough to keep the standard syntax in my head.

Comment: Take a look at the book "C# in a Nutshell" (O'Reilly) as a fast introduction -- it doesn't teach you much of the framework or how to program, but covers C# in detail.

Comment: Even better than a book, try an [automated conversion tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/). If you know .NET, you're forgiven if you forget minor syntactical differences between C# and VB.NET.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure:

```
do
{
    ...
} while (condition);
```

See [`do (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx).

Answer (score 14):

```
do
{
  // code
} while (condition)
```

Answer (score -4):

Alternatively

```
bool finished = false ;
while ( !finished )
{
   // do something
   finished = // evaluate a new foo
}
```

I've never been a huge fan of do/while

Comment: Bag your face, I am sure! do/while is a little sucky, but this sucks harder! Incidentally Pascal got it better with while/do and repeat/until which are differentiated even further by naming.

Comment: Do/While makes it very plain that the loop should execute at least once.  I really don't understand your reasoning for making things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: This is funny. I seem to have touched a real nerve here. You gonna mark me down for preferring switch over if-then-else? You should find something more important to nitpick about. You probably whine about 4 vs 3 vs 2 space indents, too.

Comment: @David. I think VB has the best syntax for this construct. It doesn't matter if the condition is at the top, the bottom, or in the middle, the frame is always Do/Loop.

Comment: I see extraneous variables, especially mutable variables, as a sign of sloppy thinking.

Answer (score -6):

```
  TopOfLoop:
            // ...
            if (condition)
            {
                goto TopOfLoop;
            }
```

No career is complete without at least one `goto`.

Comment: That's how I coded it originally. Not intentionally mind you, the goto was originally called only under an obscure case. After finding two or three more reasons to call it I realized I was just writing a loop the hard way.

Comment: If you can avoid using a `goto`, it is better to do so as it can make your code unreadable and hard to maintainable.